# Saving of 2-D array to the binary file in C language

Tags: c

I'm trying to save a 2-D array of integers to a binary file. The problem is that only the first row of the 2-D array is ​​saved. Below I have attached the outputs from which you will better understand the problem. Thanks in advance for the help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N_MAX 100

// Declaration of functions
int readMatrix(FILE *fp, int matrix[N_MAX][N_MAX]);
void printMatrix(int matrix[N_MAX][N_MAX], int size);
void switchMax(int matrix[N_MAX][N_MAX], int size);
int avg(int matrix[N_MAX][N_MAX], int size);
int sumDown(int matrix[N_MAX][N_MAX], int size);
int sumUp(int matrix[N_MAX][N_MAX], int size);
void sortMainDiagonal(int matrix[N_MAX][N_MAX], int size);

int main()
{
    int size, matrix[N_MAX][N_MAX], test[N_MAX][N_MAX];
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");

    if (fp != NULL)
    {
        size = readMatrix(fp, matrix);
        fclose(fp);

        switchMax(matrix, size);
        avg(matrix, size);
        sortMainDiagonal(matrix, size);

        printf("\nOriginal matrix: \n");
        printMatrix(matrix, size);
        
        // SAVE ON BINARY FILE
        fp = fopen("output.bin", "w");
        if (fp != NULL)
        {
            fwrite(matrix, sizeof(int), size*size, fp);
            fclose(fp);
        } else {
            printf("Error #e2");
        }

        // READ FROM BINARY FILE
        fp = fopen("output.bin", "r");
        if (fp != NULL)
        {
            fread(test, sizeof(int), size*size, fp);
            fclose(fp);

            printf("\nMatrix from file: \n");
            printMatrix(test, size);
        } else {
            printf("Error #e3");
        }
    } else {
        printf("Errore #e1");
    }
}

// Definition of functions
int readMatrix(FILE *fp, int matrix[N_MAX][N_MAX])
{
    int size = 0;
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &size);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                fscanf(fp, "%d", &matrix[i][j]);
    
    return size;
}

void printMatrix(int matrix[N_MAX][N_MAX], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void switchMax(int matrix[N_MAX][N_MAX], int size)
{
    int max = 0, row = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (matrix[j][i] > max)
            {
                max = matrix[j][i];
                row = j;
            }
        }
        matrix[row][i] = matrix[i][i];
        matrix[i][i] = max;
        max = 0;
    }
}

int avg(int matrix[N_MAX][N_MAX], int size)
{
    int avg;
    avg = (sumDown(matrix, size) + sumUp(matrix, size)) / 2;
    matrix[size-1][size-1] = avg;
    return avg;
}

int sumDown(int matrix[N_MAX][N_MAX], int size)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            sum += matrix[i][j];

    return sum;
}

int sumUp(int matrix[N_MAX][N_MAX], int size)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size-1; i++)
        for (int j = i+1; j < size; j++)
            sum += matrix[i][j];

    return sum;
}

void sortMainDiagonal(int matrix[N_MAX][N_MAX], int size)
{
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < size-1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < (size-1-i); j++)
        {
            if (matrix[j][j] > matrix[j+1][j+1])
            {
                temp = matrix[j][j];
                matrix[j][j] = matrix[j+1][j+1];
                matrix[j+1][j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Screenshot of outputs from '**printMatrix**' function:
[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zz3pm.png)

File '**input.txt**':

```
4
5 6 1 8
1 20 3 4
9 0 11 12
13 4 15 1
```

Comment: Your code doesn't test that `fwrite()` or `fread()` were successful.  You also don't show the matrix manipulation functions — so your code is not an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)
 — the same idea by a different name).  Either replace the calls with a simple initialized 2D array or provide the code.  Demonstrating the problem with a simple initialized array would be preferable. Use functions for reading/writing the binary file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show the value for `N_MAX`, but your image (which should be text in the question!) shows a 4x4 matrix.  In future, please create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

However, let's suppose `N_MAX` is 16 or more (but that `dim` is 4).  Then your code to write the matrix is writing a lot of zeroes. And skipping the other data.

Your matrix looks like:

```
13  6   1   8   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
1   15  3   4   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
9   0   20  1   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
5   4   11  26  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0   0   0   0   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0   0   0   0   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0   0   0   0   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0   0   0   0   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0   0   0   0   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0   0   0   0   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0   0   0   0   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0   0   0   0   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

And the `fwrite()` writes the first 16 integer values reading across.  As you demonstrated, 12 of those are zeros.

To write a sub-array, you'll have to write the `dim` entries of each of the matrix's first `dim` rows separately.

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < dim; i++)
{
    if (fwrite(matrix[i], sizeof(int), dim, fp) != dim)
        err_syserr("short write on row %zu of matrix\n", i);
}
```

And similarly with the `fread()` code.

<sup>The function `err_syserr()` formats and prints the given error message and the system error message associated with `errno` before exiting with a non-zero (failure) status.  A comprehensive suite of error reporting functions is available in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as files `stderr.c` and `stderr.h` in the [src/libsoq](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq) sub-directory.*\</sup>